# Group list and perform a function on the resulting matching items

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to retrieve data from a database by a grouping query and then calculate their ratio. Take for instance positions in a warehouse where you retrieve stock values for 2 days and you want to know the change ratio.

E.g.:

```
var query = from o in dbContext.Orders
            where (o.Date == firstDate) || (o.Date == secondDate)
            group o by o.Date into g
            select g;
```

How can i now (inside or outside of the query) caluclate the change ratio of the matching order items? (The ratio being defined as (newOrder.Stock / oldOrder.Stock) -1) I know how to do it by a simple somewhat verbose way, but i was hoping that there is a more elegant solution in linq.

Edit: An example of the data queried and the desired result.

```
ID Date InStock ItemID
1  15.01 5000    1
2  16.01 7000    1
3  15.01 9000    2
4  16.01 2000    2
```

This would now show an 40% increase for item 1 and an -78% decrease for item 2.

I  already did achieve this by separating the groups into two lists and then checking each list for the corresponding items in the other list. This way you can easily calculate the ratios but you create some new variables and nested foreach loops which seem unnecessary. I'm simply searching for a more elegant solution.

Comment: It will be easier to understand if you provide sample data of how the table looks like and the expected result. And also any thoughts/ways you've tried to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = from o in orders
                where (o.Date == firstDate || o.Date == secondDate)
                group o by o.ItemID into g
                select new
                {
                    ItemID = g.Key,
                    DateStart = g.ElementAt(0).Date,
                    DateEnd = g.ElementAt(1).Date,
                    Ratio = g.ElementAt(1).InStock / (float)g.ElementAt(0).InStock
                };
```

We use the fact that we know that each grouping will only contain two items (one for each date) to simply select the result of the division in a new anonymously typed item.

My example used `int` as the type for `InStock`, so feel free to remove the `(float)` cast if it's not needed.